AI Detector for Statement of Academic Purpose for Ph.D. program in applied math
I am applying to various Ph.D. programs in Applied Mathematics in the United States, and I wrote my Statement of Purpose by myself even as got help from ChatGPT on the areas where my research interest may be applied in the real world. After having written the content myself (including structuring the sentences and paragraphs), I ran it through ChatGPT to refine my Statement of Academic Purpose so that it can fix my grammar, sentence flow, etc. and check for inaccurate information. The essay that is AI refined (but not AI generated) reads really nicely, but when I ran it through AI writing detectors justdone.ai and GPTZero I get 92% and 100% in probability that my essay was AI-generated.
I am wondering if graduate committee for applied math (or any of highly technical departments like mechanical engineering) uses an AI writing detector, and if so, whether they automatically reject an application whose SoP is machine-predicted to be 90-100% likely to be written by an AI. I would understand if they have a system in place for something like that for a Ph.D. program in English, Political Science, Slavic, etc., but for a very technical programs like Applied Math there is not much variability that we can introduce. I could try to write poetically, but from what I have read online I don't think writing poetically about how I have been fascinated by math and wanted to delve deeper into its intricacies and how it was better than going to parties and something that I spent long hours would be effective, because the graduate committee in an applied math department is not much looking for that especially since a lot of people can write the same thing; they are looking for statements about specific areas of interest for research and how my experiences aligns with that.
I have read related post like this post and this post and I wasn't able to gauge how much a graduate admission committee on applied math relies on AI detector.
Here are my inquiries:
(1) Does a graduate committee for applied math (or any of highly technical departments like mechanical engineering) use an AI writing detector?
(2) If so, will they automatically reject an application whose SoP is predicted bty an AI to be 90-100% likely to be written by an AI?
(3) In general, what AI-written-probability are generally accepted by the committee as human written? 30%? 50%? 70%?

Generative AI is very new, and I would be surprised if many programs have formal procedures or percentage cutoffs. My guess is that using AI to find grammar mistakes is probably fine. But if you use AI to discover actual information, such as applications of your research interests, then I would think twice before including it. If your statement reads like you needed to resort to ChatGPT, or some non-AI tool like Google, to explain why you're interested in your proposed research topic, that's not a good look. Best wishes to you!

@academic thank you so much!

If you run your original through those two detectors, what do you get?

You may find this interesting for a general look at these tools: https://www.jeffbullas.com/ai-detector/

"The essay that is AI refined (but not AI generated)" That is not how generative AI works.

@MisterMiyagi I've copied some poorly written English prose into ChatGPT, given it the prompt "rewrite this in better English", and gotten decent results. Proofreading is definitely within the software's capability.

@academic Right but then you can't claim to have written the final product. At best it turns you into the proofreader for the AI

AI "detectors" have very high error rates, and should not really be used for this purpose (or, perhaps, any). But that does not mean they will not be...

@academic I've also got decent results from GenAI. I've also got unrelated, made up, and wrong results. If you word the query right you have a high chance that it will generate something that is close to the original - but it will still generate it from scratch, with all the pitfalls this includes.


Not likely, but professors get enough garbage from ChatGPT that they will probably see the signs.

Not automatically, but again, AI written stuff will probably either consciously or subconsciously rub the committee the wrong way.

There's definitely no standard in this.


It's Worth noting a few more things:

Your letter was AI generated. If you fed in something you wrote, got something it wrote, and handed that in, then you didn't write it.
Using an LLM to check the accuracy of your letter is a terrible idea, as that's one of its weakest points. You are very likely to shoot yourself in the foot by doing this. What if it says something wrong? What if it's right but vague enough to leave a bad impression?
AI detectors are notoriously inaccurate, and I would be hesitant to join any department that relied on them as fact. So don't take them too seriously, whether they say something is or isn't AI.

What does the detector say about your unedited letter, the one that you did not use ChatGPT for.
If you are using AI to make it look like you have skills you don't, you are likely to just hit a roadblock when you start your PhD. It's dishonest but also hurts you.
